# How to spark-submit to ZooKeeper-managed Mesos cluster (gives java.net.UnknownHostException: zk for mesos://zk:// master URL)?

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I'm running Spark 2.0.2 and Mesos 0.28.2.

I'm attempting to submit an application to Spark, using a ZooKeeper-managed Mesos cluster as the master:

```sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --verbose \
--conf spark.mesos.executor.docker.image=$DOCKER_IMAGE \
--conf spark.mesos.executor.home=$SPARK_HOME \
--conf spark.executorEnv.MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libmesos.so \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--master mesos://zk://<ip 1>:2181,<ip 2>:2181,<ip 3>:2181/mesos \
--class $APP_MAIN_CLASS \
file://$APP_JAR_PATH
```

(`<ip 1>`, `<ip 2>`, and `<ip 3>` are IPv4 addresses in the 10.0.0.0/8 block)

According to the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/running-on-mesos.html), I seem to have the right format for the master:

> The Master URLs for Mesos are in the form mesos://host:5050 for a single-master Mesos cluster, or mesos://zk://host1:2181,host2:2181,host3:2181/mesos for a multi-master Mesos cluster using ZooKeeper.

However, it appears that Spark is reading the `mesos://zk://...` string then attempting to connect to `zk`:

```
17/04/07 20:10:06 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in mesos://zk://<ip 1>:2181,<ip 2>:2181,<ip 3>:2181/mesos.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: zk
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.org$apache$spark$deploy$rest$RestSubmissionClient$$postJson(RestSubmissionClient.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$createSubmission$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$createSubmission$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:85)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.createSubmission(RestSubmissionClient.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$.run(RestSubmissionClient.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$.main(RestSubmissionClient.scala:430)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.main(RestSubmissionClient.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

How do I get Spark to recognize that it should be using the three ZooKeeper nodes rather than trying to connect to a non-existent `zk` host?

Comment: Can you try to quote it? `--master "mesos://zk://..."`? Maybe your terminal is interpreting the URI as a hostname?

Comment: @cricket_007 Previously I did have the `--conf` arguments and the master host quoted, but the terminal also sent the quotes, so I'd get errors about things like `"spark.mesos.executor.home` not being a valid option and `"mesos://` not being a valid protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** It won't work unless you either change `--deploy-mode` to `client` or use a master URL with a single Mesos host, e.g. `mesos://host:port`.

The following line gives the hint where to find the relevant code.

> 17/04/07 20:10:06 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in mesos://zk://:2181,:2181,:2181/mesos.

It looks that the message is only printed out for `--deploy-mode cluster` with Spark Standalone and Apache Mesos. Change it to the default `client` and the deployment path will change and hopefully accept the master URL.

See yourself the code that's responsible for the cluster deployment -- [RestSubmissionClient](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/rest/RestSubmissionClient.scala).

[Here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/rest/RestSubmissionClient.scala#L63) `RestSubmissionClient` says:

```
private val supportedMasterPrefixes = Seq("spark://", "mesos://")
```

which proves `mesos://` URLs are covered, but [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/rest/RestSubmissionClient.scala#L65-L69) you see the following:

```
private val masters: Array[String] = if (master.startsWith("spark://")) {
  Utils.parseStandaloneMasterUrls(master)
} else {
  Array(master)
}
```

that is printed out [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/rest/RestSubmissionClient.scala#L82) as the above INFO message that shows the URL can only be a single Mesos master.